# How to extract text from TextNode using Selenium in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to do a macro and I can't find a solution for a problem. I'm using Selenium to get data from a website. Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="milestones">
<li>
<img src="=" title="Red" data-pagespeed-url-hash="820105347" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);">
<span class="out">time 20/08/2022 12:46</span>
<strong>status Objeto aguardando retirada no endereço indicado</strong>
<br>
where it's Agência dos Correios - CONTAGEM/MG
<br>
<small>6&nbsp;horas, 2&nbsp;minutos atrás</small>
</li>
```

I want to get the *`time`*, *`status`* and *`where it is`*.

The first two I was able to get using:

```
Cells(linha, 12).value = navegadorChrome.FindElementsByClass("milestones")(1).FindElementsByTag("span")(1).Text
Cells(linha, 13).value = navegadorChrome.FindElementsByClass("milestones")(1).FindElementsByTag("strong")(1).Text
```

The last I can't get, it's the part after the first `<br>`.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the desired texts you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Extracting *time*:

  - Using *Css*:

    ```
    Cells(linha, 12).value = navegadorChrome.FindElementByCss("ul.milestones > li span.out").Text
    ```
  - Using *XPath*:

    ```
    Cells(linha, 12).value = navegadorChrome.FindElementByXPath("//ul[@class='milestones']/li//span[@class='out']").Text
    ```
- Extracting *status*:

  - Using *Css*:

    ```
    Cells(linha, 12).value = navegadorChrome.FindElementByCss("ul.milestones > li strong").Text
    ```
  - Using *XPath*:

    ```
    Cells(linha, 12).value = navegadorChrome.FindElementByXPath("//ul[@class='milestones']/li//strong").Text
    ```
- Extracting *where it's*:

  - Using *Css*:

    ```
    Cells(linha, 12).value = navegadorChrome.ExecuteScript('return arguments[0].childNodes[5].textContent;', navegadorChrome.FindElementByCss('ul.milestones > li'))
    ```
  - Using *XPath*:

    ```
    Cells(linha, 12).value = navegadorChrome.ExecuteScript('return arguments[0].childNodes[5].textContent;', navegadorChrome.FindElementByXPath("//ul[@class='milestones']/li"))
    ```

Comment: I guess my question wasnt clear enough or i didnt understand your answer:

the first 2 items are working (status and time), only the 3rd "where it's" i cant get
it's the part after the BR

Comment: i'm sorry again, but i didnt get what you mean with flaky (sorry, english isn't my native language)

Anyway, I used your last suggestion and worked, i just needed to change childNodes[5] -> childNodes[8]

the only downside is that it's copying the <br> on it and making a break line, i added a small code to remove after the data collection.

Thanks